# How do Legacy raid lockouts work in World Of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am looking to go back to old legacy raids, to attempt to farm for some rare mount drops.

Looking at specific mounts from, for example, Dragon Soul, it mentions that the mount drops:

> from Ultraxion on normal or heroic (10 or 25)

Does the difficulty share the lockout, or the number of players? Ie. Can I run 25 Normal and 25 Heroic in the same week?  How many different attempts at a mount can I have for legacy raids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In legacy raids you have one shot at the mount per lockout.

You can clear the raid once per lockout, regardless of its difficulty (since you're able to change the difficulty while you're in the raid instance).

An exception are raids with the raid finder difficulty enabled (Dragon Soul and later). You can talk to the raid's npc and clear the raid finder difficulty as well. For Dragon Soul that guy stands right before the entrance, but since you can't loot the Experiment 12B on this difficulty it doesn't help you anyway.

Comment: So for Dragon Soul, it won't matter if I clear it on 10 man normal or heroic, or 25 normal or heroic, I will only be able to clear the raid once per week? (Excluding LFR)

Comment: @Childishforlife That's correct: Once per week, regardless of difficulty (Raid Finder excluded, but you can't get the mount on Raid Finder).